# Converters not found by my Customcontrols

Tags: wpf

i have some converters declared in my app.xaml like so

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <conv:PhotoParamsConverter x:Key="PhotoParamsConverter" />
.
.
.
.
</ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

it work just fine if i use this in a usercontrol,

```
<Rectangle RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PhotoParamsConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Personne.ADH_PHOTO" />
                    <Binding Path="Personne.ADH_GENDER" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

but in a custom control (generic.xaml), i get an exception :

> cannot find staticResource PhotoParamsConverter etc etc

any idea is welcome

thanks !

Comment: add that answer so i can validate please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom control is a reusable control which can be used in various un-related projects. Reference the assembly in custom control itself, and it will work for sure.

Comment: i guess that this is some of the few WPF wierdness stuff .... i have added the converters declaration to generic.xaml and then it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DynamicResource instead, or move the converter decleration to the same XAML file as the custom control

Comment: dynamicResource is not allowed for converters, at least last time i have tried .